# Git move files accross submodules

Tags: git, mv

I have a repo `A` that uses a submodule `B`. Repo `A` has file `file.filetype` as a tracked object. I want to move that file to `B`. I don't necessarily want to keep the history, but I want to be very clear for any user of `B` that the file wasn't just newly created, but rather moved from `A` (e.g. by providing the URL to `A` and the revision where the file was moved away). Similarly on `A`, I want it to be explicit as to what happened : at this revision, the file was moved to `B` where it could be found starting at some revision.

I tried `git mv`, and it seems to have worked, but now on `A`, `git status` also tells me that `B` has been deleted, and that some (if not all) of the files of `B` are considered "untracked files", which not only strange but also worrisome. Inside `B` however everything is more or less fine - it notes the apparition of a new and therefore untracked file. It doesn't know where it came from sadly, but it has seen it.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: The reason you can't use `git mv` for this is that a submodule is a *separate Git repository*. What `git mv` does is arrange a multi-step add-and-remove change within *one* repository, but here you need to affect two different repositories. (It's almost certainly a bug that `git mv` tried to do this and made a mess of it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cancel the `git mv` (`git reset HEAD`), and run the actions manually :

- move the file on your disk from `A` to `B` using `mv`
- from submodule `B` : add file & commit, with a message which mentions the information you want : "file imported from repo A (commitid-in-A)"
- fome repo `A` : commit both the file removal, and the new state of submodule `B`, with a commit message which mentions the information you want : "file moved to B (commit-id-in-B)"